# Why website http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/ cannot be accessed right here at Shanghai China?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, cobertura

I start using **`Cobertura`** to coverage our Junit test cases, but I always get problem when I try to access http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/ to obtain the Cobertura tool, it cannot be accessed. I don't know what caused it, whether this website is expired or our government （I come from Shanghai China） prohibited this website. No matter what caused this, can somebody tell me where I can gain the  Cobertura tool and related reference document?

Thanks.

Comment: A lot of these sites (like Sourceforge) are blocked (at times) by the Great Firewall of China. You need to find a VPN. Or check some Chinese programming forums. The binaries may be available from a Maven repo, too.

Comment: In your case the link works.

Comment: As commented by @idfah, if you want I can download it and email it to you. But you know, that's eating today but starving tomorrow...

Comment: ".... can somebody tell me where I can gain the Cobertura tool and related reference document?"  You should use Google or maybe a search engine that shows you only results that are accessible in China.  Seriously, dealing with the GFoC is something that would be better asked in a China-specific forum.

Comment: Thanks. But sometimes, it lacks of enough information on our most of China technical forums.

Comment: @Igor Rodriguez, right now I have Cobertura tool, can you give me a Cobertura guide doc?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but try this tutorial: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/covering-your-tests-with-cobertura.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a proxy like [Ultimate Proxy](http://ultimateproxy.eu/). There are thousands of them in the Internet and a simple search will give you lots of results. I tried it with a locked site in UK as is The Pirate Bay and it works.

You can use as well a browser with that capabilities, such as the one released by The Pirate Bay or the [Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en)

Comment: Ultimate Proxy is not accessible from Shanghai, either ;-)

Comment: Neither are the Tor project or most of their public nodes.

Comment: @Thilo: Well, I supposed too, that's the reason I stated about the "proxy" search or, after the edit, to use a different browser.

Comment: @Thilo: One thing I'm sure: they are not infallible, so there needs to be a way missing.

Comment: @Thilo: You want me to download it and e-mail it to you?

Comment: @idfah: The messages you post in my answer aren't notified to the OP, you should comment directly in the question ;)

Comment: Guys, thanks. I got it just by accessing sourceforge.com directly and search Cobertura and download it.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.  I blame government censorship...  guess they don't want you to examine your test-case coverage :)

Comment: Totally right. This is website only for software development without something political, it makes no sense.